# php does not return message:"Record dont exist" if recod does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I made a form that will update table "Komentaar" if id "Telefoni_number" exist. But even if i enter non existing id, I still get echo "Record succesfuly updated".

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "client.id");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt update query execution
$sql = "UPDATE clientid SET Komentaar='OK' WHERE          
    Tele foni_number=5207245";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
} else  {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .             mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: The query still executes, but no rows were affected. You need to see if the record exists first, or check for [affected rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `Records were updated successfully` for if the query is executed. Ofcourse the query was executed, weather it made any change or not. You have to address your condition to, `if any rows were affected` using `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE clientid SET Komentaar='OK' WHERE Telefoni_number=5207245";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(if (mysqli_affected_rows($link)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
} else  {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that happens is that the return for this function:

```
mysqli_query($link, $sql)
```

Is always going to be true, as long as you provide a valid SQL syntax. You have successfully updated every row with that phone number, which by the way, happens to be zero. To find out whether your code really affected any rows, you can use `mysqli_affected_rows`. See the documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

So your code could be something like:

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)) {
        echo "Records were updated successfully.";
    } else {
        echo  "ERROR: No records were found!";   
    }
} else  {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .             mysqli_error($link);
}
```